# JSON Object not working with notify and wait methods

Tags: java, json, multithreading, wait, notify

I have two different threads (JAVA):

- one thread in order to make POST requests and get the answer from the REST API server, obtaining the answer in a JSON format
- another thread with the purpose of processing this information and saving it in a file.

As they are two different threads and the second thread only starts working when the first thread receives, the way to send the information that I thought is notify() and wait() methods. Nevertheless, the JSON Object that I get is not sent nor received. I tested sending another object from a created class and it works. Why the JSON object cannot be sent with notify and wait methods?

To simplify the code, I will put the response from the REST API as a string and the code related to the notify and wait (the code is implemented in thread by runnable).

First thread getting the information:

```
JSONObject jobj_gnss=new JSONObject();
String testingProcess="{\"navi\":{\"longitude\":9.015089833333333,\"latitude\":45.514222999999997,\"altitude\":151.9,\"speed\":78.2,\"travelAngle\":244.08,\"horp\":2.52,\"vertp\":5.699999999999999},\"status\":{\"locked\":true,\"quality\":2,\"type\":3,\"gps_time\":\"10h 57m 20s  October 13 2020\",\"satellites_tracked\":12,\"satellites_in_view\":15},\"res\":\"OK\"}";

   JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();      
   try {
        jobj_gnss = (JSONObject) parser.parse(testingProcess);
   } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
   }       
   synchronized (jobj_gnss )
   {    
        jobj_gnss.notifyAll();
   }
```

Second thread:

```
   JSONObject jobj_gnss;
   synchronized (jobj_gnss)
   {
        jobj_gnss.wait();
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        System.out.println(jobj_gnss.toString());
   }
```

Comment: you forgot to attach the code snippet showing the issue

Comment: your ` JSONObject jobj_gnss;` needs to be  common between thread1 & thread2. Is that true? As I am seeing you have defined it in first thred -- `JSONObject jobj_gnss=new JSONObject();` . Ideally jobj_gnss should be received by both threads either via setter or constructor.

Comment: yes, it is the same, it is set and passed when calling the thread